# Why is my html code not outputting anything?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a code cracker. I started by inputting asterisks above a series of buttons. This worked before but is not working now. This is my code I have so far:

```js
var addAster = function() {
  if (document.getElementById("asterisk").innerHTML.length != 4) {
    document.getElementById("asterisk").innerHTML += "*";
  }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <center>
    <p id="asterisk"></p>
    <button id="1" onClick="addAster()">1</button>
    <button id="2" onClick="addAster()">2</button>
    <button id="3" onClick="addAster()">3</button>
    <br />
    <button id="4" onClick="addAster()">4</button>
    <button id="5" onClick="addAster()">5</button>
    <button id="6" onClick="addAster()">6</button>
    <br />
    <button id="7" onClick="addAster()">7</button>
    <button id="8" onClick="addAster()">8</button>
    <button id="9" onClick="addAster()">9</button>
    <br />
    <button id="0" onClick="addAster()">0</button>
    <br />
  </center>
</ol>
```

I tried it before and it added asterisks above a keypad. It is not doing that anymore and I don't understand why.

Comment: When I copy-and-paste this into a test file and run it, it works fine.  All I did was add `<script> ... </script>` around the javascript.  Otherwise it was all a copy-and-paste.  This means the problem is something other than what you're showing us.

Comment: The runnable snippet works fine

Comment: Seems to be running fine, though `<center>` is not a valid child element of `<ol>`.

Comment: It's working for me on your snippet.  Check your console in the browser, if you have an error in your javascript somewhere else then it might be preventing that portion of javascript from executing.

Comment: Also ensure that your .js file is in the same folder as the .html file, since that is where your browser would be looking for it.

Comment: `This worked before but is not working now` - what did you change from before?

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache.